# Can we apply hide empty to get_the_terms?

Tags: terms

I'm using the following to populate terms on my pages...

```php
  $mget_site_url = get_site_url();

    //This gets me all the correct terms...
    $mget_the_terms = get_the_terms(get_queried_object_id(), 'ht_kb_tag');
    echo __( 'Tagged: ', 'knowall' );
    foreach ($mget_the_terms as $keygroup => $valuegroup) {
        foreach ($valuegroup as $key => $value) {
            if (($key == 'name') && ($value != 'layout-wide')) {
                //link the terms
                echo "<a href='{$mget_site_url}/tags/{$value}' rel='tag'>{$value}</a>";
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I conditionally cancel this process if the page does not have any terms? Trying to avoid the foreach error I'm seeing.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`hide_empty` hides terms that have no posts attached to them. You've got a page with no `ht_kb_tags` attached to it, if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Since [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) returns `false` if there are no terms, you should be able to prevent the `foreach()` with an `if()` statement:

```
$mget_site_url = get_site_url();

//This gets me all the correct terms...
$mget_the_terms = get_the_terms(get_queried_object_id(), 'ht_kb_tag');
if ( ! empty( $mget_the_terms ) ) {
    echo __( 'Tagged: ', 'knowall' );
    foreach ($mget_the_terms as $keygroup => $valuegroup) {
        foreach ($valuegroup as $key => $value) {
            if (($key == 'name') && ($value != 'layout-wide')) {
                //link the terms
                echo "<a href='{$mget_site_url}/tags/{$value}' rel='tag'>{$value}</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```